# Templates with Function Type Parameter Cause Compiler Error

Tags: c++, templates, generics, lambda

I have defined the following function in C++:

```
template<class Type> Type GetMedian(const vector<Type>& items, function<bool(Type, Type)> comp) {
  vector<Type> copied_items(items);
  std::nth_element(copied_items.begin(), copied_items.begin() + copied_items.size()/2, copied_items.end(), comp);
  return copied_items[copied_items.size()/2];
}
```

However, when I try to call it as `GetMedian(v, greater<uint32_t>())`, my compiler (clang) complains:

```
error: no
      matching function for call to 'GetMedian'
  GetMedian(v, greater<uint32_t>());
  ^~~~~~~~~
note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'function' against 'greater'
template<class Type> Type  GetMedian(const vector<Type>& items, function...
```

However, I do not see this error, whenever I change to not use templates, as:

```
uint32_t GetMedian(const vector<uint32_t>& items, function<bool(uint32_t, uint32_t)> comp) {
  vector<uint32_t> copied_items(items);
  std::nth_element(copied_items.begin(), copied_items.begin() + copied_items.size()/2, copied_items.end(), comp);
  return copied_items[copied_items.size()/2];
}
```

Is there any way to make my function as flexible as I am trying to?

Comment: Do you want the template to enforce that the supplied compare function has the same type as the vector or is it okay if using an incorrect compare function generates a compiler error/warning if the types are not the same?

Comment: I suspect it's a non-deducible context problem. You can work around the problem by being explicit with the template parameter. `GetMedian<uint32_t>(...)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `Type` is deduced in two spots here:

```
template<class Type> 
Type GetMedian(const vector<Type>& items, function<bool(Type, Type)> comp);
                            ^^^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

When you call it with `GetMedian(v, greater<uint32_t>())`, it'll deduce `Type` as `uint32_t` for `v`, but then it needs to deduce `function<bool(Type, Type)>` against `greater<uin32_t>`. But the latter is not of type `function`, so the deduction fails. It's *convertible* to `function<bool(uint32_t, uint32_t)>`, but conversions don't happen during the template deduction process.

Thankfully, you don't actually need a `std::function` here. It's actually worse to have it - you're giving yourself the overhead of type erasure for no reason. Just have the comparator be a separate template type:

```
template <class Type, class Comp>
Type GetMedian(const vector<Type>& items, Comp comp);
```

---

Alternatively, if you really really really want a `std::function`, you could wrap the `Type` in a non-deduced context via something like:

```
template <class T> struct non_deduced { using type = T; };
template <class T> using non_deduced_t = typename non_deduced<T>::type;

template <class T>
T median(const std::vector<T>&, std::function<bool(non_deduced_t<T>, non_deduced_t<T>)>)
```

Now, the conversion from `std::greater<uint32_t>` to `std::function<bool(uint32_t, uint32_t)>` is allowed to happen because it's only the `vector<T>` that is a deduced context, so the compiler deduces `T` to `uint32_t` and then checks if the second argument conversion works.

Comment: Could you possibly also explain why I can also fix this issue, by explicitly specifying the type when I call the function as GetMedian<uint32_t>(v, greater<uint32_t>())